# malloc() выделяет недостаточно места

Tags: c

Привет. Пишу функцию, которая должна принемать строку как параметр и выделить с помощью malloc() для этой строки отдельное место в памяти. Може я в чем то не разобрался, но это должна быть функция на подобе strdup(). Подскажите пожалуста, что делаю не так. В коде я создаю укзатель на char и выделяю память, но когда проверяю, сколько байт выделила malloc() на указатель, то в результате получаю 1. Кроме того, когда я пытаюсь скопировать входную строку в s, то получается пустая строка. Ну по крайней мере в терминале я ничего не получаю с этой строки.

Вот код программы:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char* strdub(char* str){
    int size = 0;
    while(*str){
        size++;
        str++;
    }
    printf("size: %d\n", size); //размер входной строки
    char* s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(*str) * size);
    printf("size of char: %d\n", sizeof(*s)); //проверяю, сколько символов получил
    while(*str){
        *s = *str;
        s++;
        str++;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Проверку делаю на этом:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

    int main(){
        char* hello = "hello world";
        char* get_hello = strdub(hello);    
        printf("%s\n", get_hello);

        return 0;
    }
```

И вот что получаю [image: Результат]

Comment: Ко второму while str уже убежала.

Comment: @VovaPolischuck похоже вы даже близко не понимаете, что делаете. `sizeof(*s)` (для типов данных в примере выше) будет возвращать 1 всегда и на всех платформах с которыми вы столкнётесь (хотя... существуют такие, где это будет не так). Кроме того, вы инрементируете str... а кто при копировании его востановит в исходное состояние? Потому @abyx и предложил разбить на мелкие функции: strlen, strcpy (точнее аналоги)

Comment: @Monah Tuk, вы правы. Я действительно только начал изучат Си и поэтому у мене возникают (на ваш взгляд) глупые вопросы. Но тем не менее, могли бы вы обьяснить, почему `sizeof(*s)` будет возвращать всегда 1? Разве она не должна возвращать к-во байт, что лежит в s?

Comment: По какой книжке вы изучаете? Где вы прочитали, ссылкой, цитатой, что `malloc` возвращает в `*ptr` количество аллоцированных байт? Кстати, `s` у вас тоже убегает во втором цикле и возвращаете указатель на конец блока памяти.

Comment: @VovaPolischuck: Нет. Sizeof возвращает размер значения. Какой тип у `*s`? Это `char`. Вот и размер будет 1.

Comment: @Manah Tuk, спасибо за ваш ответ. Я разобрался в чем дело.

Comment: Количество байт в s возвращает strlen(), а sizeof возвращает **размер типа данных** (для `char *s` sizeof(s) вернет размер указателя в единицах sizeof(char), который **всегда равен 1** (даже если на платформе char это несколько 8-битных байт))

Comment: @Manah Tuk, я не писал, что не 'malloc' возвращает в *ptr количество байт.

Comment: @avp, а точно, в твоей теме это обсосали. действительно, пофиг сколько битов, sizeof(char) всегда 1.

Comment: @VovaPolischuck, а как вы к этому тогда пришли: "Разве она не должна возвращать к-во байт, что лежит в s? "

Comment: @Monah Tuk, на сколько я понемаю, 'malloc' выделяет место в памяти размером байт, к-во которых указано в аргументе функции. После этого, возвращает указатель на начало выделеной памяти. Разве не так?  "Разве она не должна возвращать к-во байт, что лежит в s? " - это я думал о 'sizeof' (еще раз повторюсь).

Comment: и судя по всему, думал неправильно

Comment: @VovaPolischuck, не существует стандартной возможности узнать по указателю, на блок какого размера он указывает.

Comment: @dzhioev истину глаголишь!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделаю общий ответ :)

Для начала инлайном по коду, какие там видны проблемы:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char* strdub(char* str){    // [1]
    int size = 0;           // [2]
    while(*str){            // [3]
        size++;
        str++;              // [4]
    }
    printf("size: %d\n", size); //размер входной строки
    char* s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(*str) * size); // [5]
    // [6]
    printf("size of char: %d\n", sizeof(*s)); //проверяю, сколько символов получил              
    while(*str){ // [7]
        *s = *str;
        s++;     // [8]
        str++;
    } 

    return s;
}
```

1. Сразу учитесь соблюдать [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness). В данном случае, у вас строка `str` не модицифирует данные, хранящиеся в ней, поэтому аргумент функции стоит определить как: `const char* str`, что говорит нам о том, что в мы имеем дело с неизменяемыми данными и даём гарантию пользователю, что эти данные не будут изменены во время вызова. Как минимум это элемент самодокументирования кода и возможность избежать некоторых досадных ошибок.
2. Постарайся не использовать для размеров, которые могут быть только положительные, знаковые значения. В stdlib.h есть декларация нужного типа: `size_t`
3. По хорошему, аргумент нужно предварительно проверить на `NULL` и вернуть `NULL`, если нам передали `NULL`-аргумент.
4. Ты работешь с оригинальным указателем, соответственно теряешь его исходное значение. В некоторых случаях это оправдано, тут же он нужен тебе дальше по коду.
5. `malloc` может вернуть `NULL` и это нужно проверять. Скорее всего этого не случится в таких примитивных приложениях. Но практику стоит выработать. Стоит отметить, что в C++ проверку выделения памяти при помощи `new` делать не нужно: по стандарту он или вернёт не null, или бросит исключение. **Важно**: нужно выделять на 1 байт больше, т.к. нужно хранить признак конца строки - символ с кодом 0x00.
6. Это утверждение уже обсудили: ты разыменовываешь указатель и просишь сказать размер нулевого элемента, соответственно получаешь - 1. По стандарту `sizeof(char)` всегда будет 1. Стандартного способа узнать размер блока памяти по его указателю не существует.
7. Вот тут тебе и аукнулся пункт [4].
8. А тут ты повторяешь ошибку пункта [4], но для возвращаемого значения: мало того, что ты будешь возвращать указатель на конец. Так ещё и освободить память потом не сможешь.

Согласно вышеизложенному, исправленный код будет (ну или может) выглядеть так:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char* strdub(const char* str) {
    size_t size = 0;
    size_t i;

    if (!str)
        return NULL;

    while(str[size]) {
        size++;
    }

    printf("size: %u\n", size); //размер входной строки
    char* s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(*str) * (size + 1));
    if (s == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        s[i] = str[i];

    s[size] = '\0';

    return s;
}
```

Вот код для проверки: http://cpp.sh/2k4rv

А вот так можно реорганизовав на отдельные вызовы, которые, потом, вполне можно повторно использовать:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t str_len(const char *str) {
    size_t size = 0;
    if (!str)
        return 0;

    while (*str++)
        ++size;

    return size;
}

void str_cpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t len) {
    dst[len] = '\0';
    while (len --> 0)
        *dst++ = *src++;
}

char* strdub(const char* str) {
    size_t size = str_len(str);

    if (!size)
        return NULL;

    printf("size: %u\n", size); //размер входной строки
    char* s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(*str) * (size + 1));
    if (s == NULL)
        return NULL;

    str_cpy(s, str, size);

    return s;
}
```

И для проверки: http://cpp.sh/55w4

Comment: Забавное к п.2 - недавно читал "The Go programming language" Кернигана и Донована - так вот, они доказывают, что несмотря на то, что всякие индексы могут принимать только неотрицательные значения, все равно следует использовать для них знаковый тип `int`. А ведь Керниган - это C :) Кстати, определенный резон есть: в С++ есть для ошибок механизм исключений, а  в С или Go как показать некорректный индекс?...

Comment: Ну если понимать, во что трактуется `ptr[i]`, то можно и знаковое :) к примеру такой код вполне легитимен: http://ideone.com/rR8YT5. С ошибками же нужно делать так, что бы или пользователь её обрабатывал или же падать. Поэтому я сторонник для хранения ошибки использовать модицифируемый параметр функции, случилась ошибка - записать код или признак. Если параметр - null вызвать `abort()`.